# How to check 3d vector's collision with a polygon bounded by any 3 points in space

Tags: collision-detection, vector-graphics

I am trying to do a basic 3d ray caster that has a (spinning?) cube as a proof of concept

My current plan is to cast rays for every pixel and somehow check collision for every ray
and for each polygon defined in the world. I am currently stuck on the collision checking part.

Is my current plan even a viable solution for a ray caster or should I reconsider my plan?

Comment: Your plan is pretty much the definition of a raycaster. Arbitrary polygons might be hard to handle since there are a lot of corner cases. If you split them into triangles, the math will get a lot simpler. Anyhow - do you have a specific question?

Comment: My problem where im stuck on right now is the collision detection between a ray and a triangle - i have found no instantly useful resources on the internet either

Comment: Really? There are tons, like [1](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/ray-triangle-intersection-geometric-solution), [2](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep557/14au/lectures/triangle_intersection.pdf), [3](https://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/maths/ray-triangle-intersection/), [4](https://cmu-graphics.github.io/Scotty3D/pathtracer/ray_triangle_intersection), [5](https://cadxfem.org/inf/Fast%20MinimumStorage%20RayTriangle%20Intersection.pdf).

Comment: super, these were exactly what i was looking for thank you!